# which server should i install the wf manager

Tags: workflow, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager

I have two SharePoint servers

- web
- application

I need to install the workflow manager and I don't know which server should I use?!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install on any server but i would do on the Application server. Make sure you install WFM client on the WFE.